# Android Nougat 7.1 resets Locale after launching WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-7.1-nougat

We got a weird behavior with Android N 7.1 ( API-25 ) That after Launching WebView, system enforces reseting Locale to device locale. That overrides used locale (for localization) on application. Easy way to reproduce that is to get a localization on app. and launch a WebView. Then you won't see localized content any more until you relaunching app again. That happens only on Android-7.1 (API-25)

Here is how I switch Locale which is working in all APIs:

```
 public void switchToCzLocale() {
        Locale mLocale = new Locale("cs","CZ");// it can be any other Locale
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources()
                .getConfiguration();
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        config.setLocale(mLocale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

I have uploaded a sample to reproduce that issue with more details on:

https://github.com/mabuthraa/WebView-android7-issue

Please any idea if this behavior is a bug or probably bad implantation of changing locale.

Here is the link to issue ticket on Android group: [Issue 218310:   [developer preview] Creating a WebView resets Locale to user defaults](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218310)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is my workaround solution.

We resolved that issue by enforcing setting locale again after initializing webView and before loading content:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  MyApp.getApplication().switchToCzLocale();
}
```

For example in WebActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
          MyApp.getApplication().switchToCzLocale();
        }
        mWebView.loadData(getString(R.string.web_content), "text/html", "charset=UTF-8");
    }
```

MyApp:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

import java.util.Locale;


public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp sApplication;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        switchToCzLocale();
        sApplication = this;
    }

    public static MyApp getApplication() {
        return sApplication;
    }

    public void switchToCzLocale() {
        Locale mLocale = new Locale("cs","CZ");
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources()
                .getConfiguration();
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        config.setLocale(mLocale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I hope that may help,'.

**Still Im looking for a better solution.**

Comment: for now this the only solution :|

Comment: @Maher Have you found a better solution for the problem? I've been using the workaround you've mentioned above for a couple of months now, but recently I've received complains about the same problem again. The issue is still not resolved in the google tracker either, and I can't really thing of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem gave me some headache as well especially because Google thinks that it is not a bug on their side. However, this is definitely not a desired behavior in an app that the language gets changed just when opening a WebView.

Our solution does not depend on a hardcoded language and is adapted for Android 7+. First, add this code to your app build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs rootProject.ext.available_languages
        buildConfigField "String[]", "AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES", "{\"${rootProject.ext.available_languages.join("\",\"")}\"}"
    }
}
```

And add the following code to your root build.gradle:

```
ext {
    available_languages = ["en", "de"]
}
```

These two code blocks define the list of available `strings.xml` files and puts the list in the `BuildConfig.AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES` field.

Now, we can define a `BaseActivity`, from which all activities should extend, with the following code:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        val locale = getFirstAvailableLocale(newBase)
        val context = createContextWithLocale(locale, newBase)
        super.attachBaseContext(context)
    }

    private fun getFirstAvailableLocale(context: Context): Locale {
        val availableLanguages = BuildConfig.AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES // Gets list of available languages defined in the build.gradle file
        val locales = context.resources.configuration.locales
        for (i in 0..locales.size()) {
            if (locales[i].language in availableLanguages) {
                return locales[i]
            }
        }
        return locales[0]
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun createContextWithLocale(locale: Locale, baseContext: Context): Context {
        val resources = baseContext.resources
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        val localeList = LocaleList(locale)
        LocaleList.setDefault(localeList)
        configuration.setLocales(localeList)
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            baseContext.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
        } else {
            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
            baseContext
        }
    }
}
```

You can even extend this solution to support different regions but then you would have to split the strings from the resConfigs into the language and region as the `Locale` class does not recognize the language tag correctly (e.g. de-rDE needs to be defined in resConfigs but `Locale` would be de_DE)